# Newline character produced by `echo`, is it always there when using no options, regardless of shell?

Tags: text-processing, echo, newlines, printf

Although I have read [Stephane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/126755) concentrated on basically all aspects of `echo` vs `printf`, I am unsure if it also answers my question, which stands:

The newline character produced by `echo`, is it always there without using any option on virtually all systems?:

I have a POSIX script, where the relevant part is:

```sh
printf '\n'; printf '\n' >&2
```

And I ask myself, do I need to stick with `printf` in this case too?

It could look better:

```sh
echo; echo >&2
```

But I am no expert, so I'm unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The newline character produced by `echo`, is it always there without using any option on virtually all systems?

I don't know if it's indeed always there on *all* systems, yet it *should* be there on all POSIX-derived systems. According to the [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)

> DESCRIPTION
>   The `echo` utility writes its arguments to standard output, followed by a <newline>. If there are no arguments, only the <newline> is written.

And later

> Implementations shall not support any options.

While some implementations do support few options, in a case of no option given they should fall back to POSIX. So yes, they should produce a newline character.

In theory, if you're afraid `echo` doesn't comply, you may as well be afraid `printf` doesn't comply. In practice I would rather trust `printf` anyway while trying to write robust code, because it's in general the right tool and there's no point in dropping it in some edge case (see "Stepping beyond simple case" in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1114763/432690) to understand what I mean).